# Google sheet is changing format of cell values when retrieving using .getValues

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

On google sheet I have this values

```
Id  Date         In      Out
8   12/9/2016    22:00   22:00
50  12/5/2016    07:40   17:32
50  12/6/2016    07:41   17:42
50  12/7/2016    07:20   17:40
50  12/8/2016    07:22   20:56
50  12/9/2016    07:35   18:11
50  12/10/2016   07:31   07:31
50  12/11/2016   04:27   04:27
50  12/12/2016   07:52   18:02
```

When I retrieve the values to Google sites, it converts the Time In and Time Out to something like this

```
2016-12-09  Sat Dec 30 1899 21:54:38 GMT+0800 (HKT) Sat Dec 30 1899 21:54:38 GMT+0800 (HKT)
```

It converts the Time In from **07:40** to **Sat Dec 30 1899 07:40:39 GMT+0800** (HKT)

How can I revert it back to 07:40 or 7:40 AM?

This is how I get the values:

```
var sheetToView = ss.getSheetByName("TempManila");
var rangeToView = sheetToView.getDataRange();
var values = rangeToView.getValues();
values.shift();

var temp = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
  temp.push([
    values[i][0].toString(),
    values[i][1].toString(),
    values[i][2].toString(),
    values[i][3].toString(),
    values[i][4].toString(),
    values[i][5].toString(),
    values[i][6].toString(),
    values[i][7].toString(),
    values[i][8].toString(),
    values[i][9].toString(),
  ]);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Changing .getValues() to .[getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) may help.
From the documentation: it...

> returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a two-dimensional array of displayed values, indexed by row, then by column. The values will be of type String. The displayed value takes into account date, time and currency formatting, including formats applied automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data without changing format using "setNumberFormat('@')". https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat

Please change from

```
var rangeToView = sheetToView.getDataRange();
```

to

```
var rangeToView = sheetToView.getDataRange().setNumberFormat('@');
```

If it doesn't work, feel free to tell me.